# Why i am unable to redirect to the given page using Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have written my `web.config` file as follows

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Index.aspx" defaultUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="20"/>
</authentication>
```

Which works good locally but when i am going to live i am unable to see the `Index.aspx` as my default page. Instead of this i am able to see `Default.aspx` i have. What's the problem behingdthis

Comment: Do you mean that a user is automatically directed to Default.aspx when they type in the URL of the website?

Comment: `Tim B James` Yeah when i hit some `xyz.com` it is redirecting me to `default` page instead of the page given

Comment: It feels like perhaps you're already being recognised as logged in and therefore forwarded past your login page. Do you get the same thing if you clear all your temporary internet files/cookies?

Comment: Hi `dougajmcdonald` i tried that too but didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, and going on your comment.

Your users are going to `Default.aspx` because in your IIS settings, `Default.aspx` will be set as the [default document](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument). You want to specify `Index.aspx` instead.

The authenitcation settings only take effect when you are disallowing access to certain areas of your website using [Location Authorisation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)

Comment: Locally you possibly have the Index.aspx page set as your startup page within your project.

Comment: So we have to change the page as per the document and to replace right

Comment: Yeah you can update the default document, or deny access to anyone who is not logged in. This way they will be directed to the login URL